# Android NoClassDefFoundError while programming with scala

Tags: android, eclipse, scala, dynamic

I recently had the following error, working with Scala 2.10 on Android 4.0.3 device, with Eclipse 3.7 as the IDE.
A sentence written:

```
val r = new Rectangle
```

was causing the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Rectangle
```

I looked into my code, and I defined Rectangle this way:

```
abstract class GameObject extends [Lot of traits] with Dynamic { ... }
class Rectangle extends GameObject { ... }
```

I found the solution. by removing the `with Dynamic` from the definition of my class, I was able to remove the error.
Even adding `import scala.Dynamic` and `import scala.language.dynamics` did not solve the problem.

Are there general problems to use [scala Dynamics](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic) in Android?

Comment: Any chance proguard is removing something it shouldn't? Give a try to keep scala.* classes and tell us what happens.

Comment: How and where should I write something to tell proguard to keep scala classes?

Comment: That depends on how you are building your projects. If you are using the default build system http://bit.ly/15USgBT.

Comment: I am using the AndroidProguardScala plug-in